# Setting singles values with YamlDotNet

Tags: c#, yamldotnet

I'm a newbie to YAML, YamlDotNet and not very experienced with C#. Today I created a small app that is loading and analyzing a nested YAML file, extracting each single Key/Value pair with the RepresentationModel. Everything works fine.

While processing the structure I want to change some of the Value properties and finally I want to save the changed YAML structure into another file.

How to change single Value properties? It doesn't seem to be possible. entry.Value is read-only?!

There are some additonal requirements that I don't know how to solve:
 - Can I access comments stored in the YAML structure while parsing?
 - When saving a changed structure how to preserve comments and
   indention so that it can be compared to the original file?

Any feedback is highly appreciated.
Many thanks
Hanibani

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear from your question what is `entry`, but if it's a `KeyValuePair` then your best move would be

```
entry = new KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>(entry.Key, newValue);
```

Where `TKey` and `TValue` are the types of the key and the value (as name suggests)

Comment: Hello Marian, Thanks for your help, I didn't hoped to get an answer after 8 months.  newValue is a string and can't be casted to YamlNode. How to get this done? Sorry for such newbie questions.

Comment: Please discard my comment. I was able to sort it out. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi @Hanibani. I have the same problem. How did you solve the issue? Thank you, Igor